# Is there a way to make a drive display its real capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, usb-flash-drive

So, as we all (hopefully) know, computers run on a base-2 numbering system (bytes, etc.). The sizes of files and drives are calculated based on how many bytes that file takes up or how many bytes can be stored in that drive.

However, computers and manufacturers look at sizes differently. Let's look at an 8 GB flash drive, for instance.

From a manufacturer's standpoint, 8 GB = 8,000 MB = 8,000,000 KB = 8,000,000,000 bytes. This amount in bytes is what is labeled in the flash drive.

From a computer's standpoint, 8 GB = 8,192 MB = 8,388,608 KB = 8,589,934,592 bytes. This amount in bytes is what the computer *considers* to be 8 GB.

The problem is that if the flash drive is really the size that manufacturers consider to be 8 GB, they are undercutting us by 590 MB, or over half a gig. If the flash drive is *actually* 8 GB (in terms of the base-2 numbering system), then there is currently 590 MB of space that we cannot use.

Which system accurately describes the drive's real size? If it really is 8 GB, how can we gain access to that extra 590 MB?

Remember that this only scales up as drives get bigger.

**NOTE:** Please tell me what tags this needs, I couldn't really find any that pertained well enough to my question, so I put some drive-related ones.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix - might be a good reference here

Comment: When a manufacturer puts '8GB' they mean base 10, computers speak in base 2 (binary). So you will _NEVER_ have that extra 590 MiB .. it's simply a marketing ploy and nothing more .. it's been a hot debate amongst the purest since it started 20+ years ago .. the answer, unfortunately, is to remember that you're getting shorted (unless you buy an SSD).

Comment: @txtechhelp given that the Sandisk pages for their SSD drives all have a "1MB=1,000,000 bytes." disclaimer at the bottom of every page I don't think you can forget it with SSDs either. Just assume all storage devices are in "marketing" megabytes. Look just above the bottom bar in the disclaimer area: https://www.sandisk.com/home/ssd/extreme-pro-ssd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Which system accurately describes the drive's real size?

On Windows use the Win32_DiskDrive WMI class:

> The Win32_DiskDrive WMI class represents a physical disk drive as seen by a computer running Windows. Like the Win32_LogicalDisk WMI class, it has lots of properties, as listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx.

Source [Getting a list of logical and physical drives from the command line](https://ardamis.com/2012/08/21/getting-a-list-of-logical-and-physical-drives-from-the-command-line/).

To retrieve the actual sizes run the following command:

```
wmic diskdrive get caption, size
```

Example output:

```
> wmic diskdrive get caption, size
Caption                            Size
WDC WD5000LPVX-08V0TT5             500105249280
SanDisk Cruzer USB Device          64009128960
Seagate Expansion Desk USB Device  3000582144000
```

Comment: What about OS's like Ubuntu?

Comment: @Creep2DJ For Ubuntu see the AskUbuntu question [What command do I use to find physical disk size?](//askubuntu.com/q/332949)